# Shopify newsletter signup popup for first visitors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, shopify-app

I'm going to add a newsletter signup popup for my `shopify` site.
I know there are a lot of `shopify apps` that support this feature. But I'm going to add it without `shopify apps` because I need [Ometria](https://www.ometria.com/) integrated. (All `shopify apps` don't have the feature)

So the problem is I need to check for visitors if they are first visitors or not. Then I can create a popup dialog that has newsletter form using any `jQuery` popup dialog plugins.

Or if there are a free `shopify app` that has the feature which shows the 
 popup dialog for first visitors and can be added a custom form using `HTML` not their own form builder.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just set a cookie once he enters the site and check it and you will be good to go.

Comment: thanks @drip. I think that's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to comment, but you can use a cookie to track whether or not the user has visited your site before.

If they haven't you can then run the `jQuery` necessary to display the popup.

That said, it may also be worth mentioning that you need to be careful with the way in which you implement your popup or really any interstitial (including warnings for the use of cookies on your site). Google now actively penalizes sites that don't use good practice, so it may be worth reading up on it a bit.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/helping-users-easily-access-content-on.html